# Sequence Convergence using bounding sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Consider the sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_n = F_{n+1}/F_n$ for $n \in \Bbb N$,
>   where $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers. Show that this sequence
>   converges to $\phi =(\sqrt{5}+1)/2$.

Can someone help me? The hint they give me is to find two bounding sequence, but I don't understand how this could help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the following facts, then conclude (bounding sequences appear after step 3):

1. $\phi$ satisfies $\phi = 1 + \dfrac{1}{\phi}$,
2. $a_{n+1} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{a_n}$ for all $n$,
3. deduce from 1 and 2 that  $|a_{n+1}-\phi| \leq \frac{1}{\phi}|a_n - \phi|$ for all $n$.

Comment: Can you be more precise? I don't understand last point

Comment: @user3685627: done. Did you already prove the first two facts?

Comment: Well the second point It's kinda of obvious cause Fibonacci is defined for n>=2

Comment: @user3685627: this is not what "bounded sequence" mean.

Comment: mmm So what should I have to do in order to prove these 3 points?

Comment: @user3685627: think, try, fail, think, try, fail,...,think, try, understand.

Comment: "Think, try, fail": indeed! $8/5 < 5/3$. Also $21/13 < 13/8$. And so on. So your first fact is false.

Comment: @TonyK: Yep, I always do what I say!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** The $n$-th Fibbonacci number is given by,

$$F_n=\frac{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}},$$

where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ratio.

Then,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}
&=\frac{\phi^{n+1}-(-\phi)^{-n-1}}{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}\\
&=\frac{\phi^{n+1}-(-1)^{-n-1}\phi^{-n-1}}{\phi^n-(-1)^{-n}\phi^{-n}}\\
&=\frac{\phi-(-1)^{-n-1}\phi^{-2n-1}}{1-(-1)^{-n}\phi^{-2n}}.
\end{align}$$